# Ubuntu 20.04 stuck at loading/boot screen!

Tags: 20.04, boot-repair

My Ubuntu 20.04 is stuck at the boot screen, it shows only a flashing cursor and nothing. It briefly showed the message below.

[image: error in boot screen]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: From the screenshot, seems like it was waiting for the Network Manager to finish the initialisation. May be the network was not reachable or something. Usually, if it failed to connect ... it should timeout and move forward without the network.